# literal type in constexpr expression and template parameter

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, non-type-template-parameter, constexpr-function

Why do I can use non constexpr literal types in constexpr functions(such as reflection) and it can be returned as constexpr, but I can't use such types in template non-type parameters?

```
class Point {
    public:
        constexpr Point(double xVal = 0, double yVal = 0) noexcept
        : x(xVal), y(yVal)
        {}

        constexpr double xValue() const noexcept { return x; }
        constexpr double yValue() const noexcept { return y; }

        constexpr void setX(double newX) noexcept { x = newX; }
        constexpr void setY(double newY) noexcept { y = newY; }
    private:
        double x, y;
};

template <long long N>
void F()
{
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
}

constexpr Point reflection(const Point& p) noexcept
{
    Point result;
    result.setX(p.xValue());
    result.setY(p.yValue());
    return result; // returning literal non consexpr type
}
 
int main()
{
    constexpr Point p;
    F<static_cast<long long>(reflection(p).xValue())>(); //result returned from reflection can be used here

    Point p1;
    p1.setX(123);
    F<static_cast<long long>(p1.xValue())>(); //error: the value of ‘p1’ is not usable in a constant expression
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`constexpr` is not a property of a type. It is a specifier on a variable/function declaration.

Objects whose lifetime begins within the evaluation of the constant expression are usable in that constant expression and don't need to be declared `constexpr`.

The expression that needs to be a constant expression here is in the first case

```
static_cast<long long>(reflection(p).xValue())
```

The variable `result` inside `reflection` lives only during the evaluation of that expression and `p` is declared `constexpr`. Therefore both are usable in the constant expression.

In the second case the expression

```
static_cast<long long>(p1.xValue())
```

is required to be a constant expression. This uses `p1`, but `p1` is not declared `constexpr` and its lifetime started before the evaluation of the expression, so it is not usable in the constant expression. More precisely the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion required in `xValue()` violates the requirements for a constant expression.

Comment: but such objects need to have literal types when they are used in constant expressions?

Comment: @Vanconts Yes, they need to have literal types.